# ASPxGridView cell non editable on tab key press

Tags: c#, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am having one small issue with aspxgridview that I hove you can assist me with.  My grid have 6 columns, 2 combobox coulmn, 1 ASPxDateEdit column, and 3 DataTextColumns like unit, price and and total.

1. I want that when I go with in-line edit mode, moving in a grid row by tab key, it should not go into "total" text box column.
2. But when I will do a mouse click on this column (total text box) it should be available in edit mode for editing the total.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With in-Line edit Mode:

Code Behind:

```
(grid.Columns["Total"] as GridViewDataColumn).EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
```

Or Designer: Column [Total] -> EditFormsettings -> Visible set to false.

Rg.